# Top n closest numbers from a python list

Tags: python

I often need to select a certain amount of numbers from a list, so that they are the closest ones to some other certain number.

For example:

```
x0 = 45
n = 3
mylist = [12,32,432,43,54,234,23,543,2]
```

So, how do I select `n` numbers from the list which are the closest ones to `x0`? Is there some built-in method?

```
topN = [43, 54, 32]
```

---

The way I see is below, however it looks a bit convoluted:

```
diffs = sorted([(abs(x - x0), x) for x in mylist])
topN = [d[1] for d in diffs[:n]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`heapq.nsmallest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest):

```
heapq.nsmallest(n, iterable[, key])
```

> Return a list with the n smallest elements from the dataset defined by iterable. key, if provided, specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in the iterable: key=str.lower Equivalent to: sorted(iterable, key=key)[:n]

So in your particular case:

```
import heapq
x0 = 45
n = 3
mylist = [12,32,432,43,54,234,23,543,2]
heapq.nsmallest(n, mylist, key=lambda x: abs(x-x0))
```

This uses less overhead because it discards elements as they exceed `n`.

Comment: Is it any better than simple sorting? Does it somehow use the fact that I don't need to sort the whole list?

Comment: yes, it's better. it pushes values into the `heap` up to `n` size, so there's only one loop through, no full copy of the list, and quick discards of bad values

Comment: Or you can create your own binary tree using x0 as the median and split left nodes < x0 and right nodes > x0. But heapq is already using some kind of binary tree.

Comment: there's probably some initial overhead that carries too much weight for just 9 elements. it works best with thousands or millions of elements

Comment: @sashkello use of heap means time complexity is O(k logn) where k is the size of the heap (instead of O(n logn) for sorting) so there are some time savings.  Note that this is *algorithmic* complexity - when k is close to n, `sorted` often ends up being faster because timsort is insanely good.

Answer (score 0):

Can be alternatively done using sorting by custom function:

```
sorted(mylist, key = lambda x : abs(x-x0))[:n]
```

It is slower than `heapq.nsmallest` in terms of time complexity, however has less overhead and thus is more efficient for small lists.

Comment: Please see some discussion here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question I already know one of the possible answers when I post the question and I feel like it should be in an answer rather than question. I want, however, to see what other answers could possibly be out there. This is Q&A site after all and answers should get in to "answer" part of it :)

Comment: @sjcipher Also, I don't like when question goes: "I've done this, how can I improve?" - because with some probability the answer is "no way". When I post this as an answer instead, I can just accept it afterwards if this is the case, maintaining the proper structure of Q&A.

Comment: i agree with that, thats true.